# How do I use kinesis firehose from iOS without the user creating a username and password?

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-cognito, amazon-kinesis-firehose, aws-userpools

I'm building out an SDK in Swift that collects data from a phone and sends it to AWS. However, there will be a lot of "stream" data and the user will not have to sign in to anything as it will run silently in the app.

My current implementation sends the data through API calls and sends this data to API Gateway -> Kinesis Stream -> Kinesis Firehose -> S3. I'd assume it's more efficient to write directly to Kinesis Firehose but from what I've read, this requires Cognito and User Pools.

Is there a way to write directly to Kinesis Firehose without IAM Access? Alternatively, should I create a login and password for a Cognito based on uuid and some sort of hashed password based on the user and then send to Kinesis Firehose? Or should I continue using my current implementation?